# htop like monitor for docker stats?

Tags: linux, docker

`docker stats` gives a good overview of the cpu/mem/net io/disk io as text.

Does there exist a `htop` like monitor that shows the docker stats?

---

Same questino posted in DevOps sister site [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/10611/19335)

**Suggested answer**

`ctop` at https://github.com/bcicen/ctop

Comment: Top-like interface for container metrics: https://github.com/bcicen/ctop

Comment: This question is extreamely helpful for engineers who work with docker container!

Comment: You guys may want to vote for this sister site proposal https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `docker top` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/top/ you can use the same options as for `ps`  so you may have details

An example:

```
docker top mycontainerid o pid cmd
```

Comment: It is only for one container and it doesn't have a ncurses like UI.

Comment: so try `docker run -it --pid=host jess/htop`

Comment: If you want a list of all running containers, and how much resources each takes, try out `ctop`, works from inside a container, on the host or even remotely: github.com/bcicen/ctop

Comment: Alternative link: https://ctop.sh